# I want to make an audio visualizer that accumulates the input from a f-curve data rather than vacillates between values. How can I accomplish this?

Tags: scripting, audio, fcurves, custom-properties

The specific effect I'm going for is a noise texture on an object to move a little bit farther each time a sound is played from an audio file. Essentially I want it to accumulate the values from the f-curve rather than simply following it.

I've gone down a few different paths here to no avail. The closest I've gotten is doing the following:

- make location keyframe on an empty on the x-axis
- bake sound to f-curves (sound to samples in the most recent version)
- create a custom property (in code below named "S_A") on the desired object ("Cube" in code below)
- create a "sum value" driver on that custom property that follows the empty on the x-axis
- create a second custom property (in code below named "Accumulated_Z") that accumulates the values from the first using a python script (script below)

The script actually works and the "Accumulated_Z" custom property really does accumulate the values but it seems that it won't "Update Dependencies" automatically no matter what I try.

I feel like there may be a much simpler solution that I'm not seeing. Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Code below:

```
import bpy

# Ensure the Cube object exists
if 'Cube' not in bpy.data.objects:
    print("Error: 'Cube' object not found in the scene.")
else:
    obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']

# Initialize the accumulator property if it doesn't exist
if "Accumulated_Z" not in obj:
    obj["Accumulated_Z"] = 0.0
    print("'Accumulated_Z' property added to 'Cube'.")

# Previous value storage - initialize with the current value of S_A
if "prev_S_A" not in obj:
    obj["prev_S_A"] = obj.get("S_A", 0.0)  # Using get() to avoid key errors
    print("'prev_S_A' initialized.")

def accumulate_sound_amplitude(scene):
    current_value = obj.get("S_A", 0.0)  # Using get() to safely access "S_A"
    prev_value = obj["prev_S_A"]
    
    print(f"Current S_A: {current_value}, Previous S_A: {prev_value}")  # Debug print

    # Check if there's an increase
    if current_value > prev_value:
        increase = current_value - prev_value
        obj["Accumulated_Z"] += increase
        print(f"Increased Accumulated_Z to: {obj['Accumulated_Z']}")  # Debug print

    # Update the previous value for the next frame
    obj["prev_S_A"] = current_value

# Remove existing handlers to avoid duplicates
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()

# Add the accumulate_sound_amplitude function to the frame change handlers
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(accumulate_sound_amplitude)

print("Setup complete. The Z location will now accumulate based on sound amplitude.")
```